# Java heap space does not get increased using -Xmx 1g

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am doing some fancy stuff, where I really need to allocate about 1 GB.

My Computer has 8GB 64 bit System, so that's not a problem.

I use `-Xmx 4g` to increase my heap space, but sadly enough that doesn't work at all.

I use:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long totalMem = rt.totalMemory();
long maxMem = rt.maxMemory();
long freeMem = rt.freeMemory();
double megs = 1048576.0;

System.out.println ("Total Memory: " + totalMem + " (" + (totalMem/megs) + " MiB)");
System.out.println ("Max Memory:   " + maxMem + " (" + (maxMem/megs) + " MiB)");
System.out.println ("Free Memory:  " + freeMem + " (" + (freeMem/megs) + " MiB)");
```

Which shows me:

```
Total Memory: 259522560 (247.5 MiB
Max Memory:   259522560 (247.5 MiB)
Free Memory:  0 (0 MiB)
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Does anyone of you have an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

It is `-Xmx4g`, without a space in between.

Comment: -Xmx4g it doesnt make a difference, it still doesnt work

Comment: @Daniel if it does not help, then you are maybe passing the arguments in the wrong way? Can you give us the whole command line you are using? You must set the argument before the class name. If you put it after, it would explain why it did not fail with your superflous blank.

Answer (score 4):

Tell us your whole command line, I suspect you use:

```
java -jar file.jar -Xmx 4G
```

or

```
java -cp file.jar package.Main -Xmx 4G
```

Both are wrong, you can use one of the following instead:

```
java -Xmx4G -jar file.jar
java -Xmx4G -cp file.jar package.Main
```

Answer (score 1):

-Xmx4g (with no space, as has been pointed out already) will only set a maxium for the heap size not automatically assign the full amount on startup.

-Xms4g may well do this, as this sets the initial heap size.

Typically people set these as a pair on app startup. For example when launching servers using classes that generate a lot of runtime-generated classes...

-Xms256m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: maxMemory() is supposed to show the -Xmx setting even when the memory was not commited or used. So I guess the Xms was not the problem here, but it is good to point out.

Answer (score 1):

The `-Xmx` option sets the *maximum* size of the heap.  But the JVM typically starts with a smaller heap, and expands it as required.

To tell the JVM the initial size of the heap, use the `-Xms` option as well; e.g.

```
   java -Xmx4g -Xms4g ...
```

tells Java to us a 4g heap, and set that size from the start.  Note that this doesn't necessarily cause all of that physical / virtual memory to be allocated to the process immediately.  However the heap's space sizes should be set in proportion to the nominal initial size.

(As others have noted, these are atomic options; i.e. don't put a space before `4g`.)

---

If you *know* that you will need a large part of the requested heap "pretty soon", then setting `-Xms` avoids (repeated) resizing of the heap during start-up.  But if your `-Xms` value is significantly more than you are likely to need, then you may end up using system resources unnecessarily.